# How to pass values from sale to invoice (through invoiceable lines) in odoo10?

Tags: odoo-10

class SaleAdvancePaymentInv(models.TransientModel):

```
_inherit = "sale.advance.payment.inv"

@api.multi

def _create_invoice(self, order, so_line, amount):

    inv_obj = super(SaleAdvancePaymentInv, self)._create_invoice(order, so_line, amount)

    inv_obj.write({'service_id':order.service_id.id})
```

---

This is my code.service id does not pass sale order to invoice through **invoiceable lines.**

But when I use **downpayment** the service id is passed to invoice.

***What is the reason behind this.?**

**How to pass the values through the invoiceable line?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@api.multi
def _prepare_invoice(self):
    dict_obj = super(SaleOrder, self)._prepare_invoice()
    dict_obj.update({'service_id': self.service_id.id})
```

I override the prepare invoice function update the service value in dictionary

Comment: why does this not work anymore in the current version?

Comment: which version. odoo14?

Comment: I guess. It's Flectra 1.7 (Community Edition)

Comment: i created a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067896/how-do-i-transfer-data-from-sale-order-to-invoice-when-clicking-on-create-invoi

Comment: I am not used Flectra but i think this will be works in odoo14

Comment: Its the same codebase, I guess. At least the Sales class seems to be unchanged.

Comment: Could it be a writing permission problem?